# Solving double sum for the PMF of random variable Z=X+Y-1

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, summation

Let $X,Y$ be two random variables with joint probability mass function
$$p_{X,Y}(k,l)=\begin{cases}
\frac{6}{\pi^2(k+l-1)^3},\, k,l\in\mathbb{N},\\
0, \text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
Now I need to calculate the pmf of $Z=X+Y-1$.
We have
$$p_Z=\frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{l\in\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{1}_{\{k+l-1=m\}}\cdot\frac{1}{(k+l-1)^3}$$
But I don't know how I can calculate this sum. Any help is greatly appreciated.